# Jersey @NotNull validation not working

Tags: java, validation, rest, maven, jersey

I want to use the Jersey bean validation, so here 's the code for that,

Jersey version is : 1.17.1 for me

Here is the Maven Dependency I am using, given [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

Also the code I am using is:

```
@POST
@Path("abc")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postAbc(@NotNull @HeaderParam(value="AccessId") String accessId){
  ////
}
```

Now my question is when I don't pass the HeaderParam of AccessId, even then it is not showing any exception or so, so my question is should I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

You should either migrate to jersey 2 and use the approach presented [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) or use AOP for that.